# How can it be, that ConcurrentHashMap has no keySet() method?

Tags: java, matlab, java-8, java-7, nosuchmethoderror

I am debugging `Java` code, called from `Matlab` and getting an exception:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
```

how can it be, that library class has no library method?

**UPDATE**

Matlab is using `Java7`. The code I call was compiled for `Java8` and contains syntax

```
for (Tag t : matrix.keySet()) {
```

i.e. `Java8`-specific. Although, it is claimed, that it should be binary compatible with `Java7`, otherwise there was no sense to do many of compromises in `Java8`.

Comment: What version of Java are you running? At first glance it looks like Matlab is expecting the Java 8 version but you might be running 7.

Comment: but the keySet() method has existed for the ConcurrentHashMap since Java 6... I just checked 6, 7, 8 and they all have the method keySet()... @Zircon

Comment: @Raz_Muh_Taz true, but in Java 7 `keySet` returns a `Set<K>` per its signature while in Java 8 it returns `ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView<K,V>`.

Comment: @Zircon but isn't it claimed, that `Java8` code is binary compatible with `Java7`? Here we see, that I can't use `Java8` jar in `Java7` machine.

Comment: @Dmis You can use `Java7` code in `Java8` machine, but not `Java8` code in `Java7` machine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692626/is-jdk-upward-or-backward-compatible

Comment: @Dims What makes you expect you can take code compiled against Java 8, and expect all the methods that were present in Java 8 to be present in Java 1.0?  That's not how compatible evolution works.  You can safely go _forward_ in time -- great care is taken to make sure this is true -- but not _backwards_.

Comment: @AdamSiemion then why didn't they do many things, like, runtime generics? It was approved by backwards binary compatibility.

Comment: @BrianGoetz what is used, is just for-each loop. It should be compiled  awayand work in previous Java, why not?

Comment: @Dims you compiled the for loop using Java 8, put in a jar and then tried to execute in the Java 7 machine?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25705596/1441122).

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 the `ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()` return type has been changed. 
In Oracle JDK 7:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    return (ks != null) ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet());
}
```

while in Oracle JDK 8:

```
public KeySetView<K,V> keySet() {
    KeySetView<K,V> ks;
    return (ks = keySet) != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySetView<K,V>(this, null));
}

public static class KeySetView<K,V> extends CollectionView<K,V,K>
    implements Set<K>, java.io.Serializable {
```

Comment: So, `Java` is not portable from `1.7` to `1.8`?

Comment: @Dims This is a perfectly compatible change.  `KeySetView<K,V>` extends (is-a) `Set<K>`.  That makes the implementation of `keySet()` in `ConcurrentHashMap` a _covariant override_ of `keySet()` in `Map`.  And the change from returning `Set<K>` to the more refined `KeySetView<K,V>` is both a binary- and source-compatible change.  Code written or compiled against the 7 libraries will still work on 8.

Comment: @BrianGoetz what coolness and compatibility is it, if it does not work? There was no sense to use "covariant override" or any other things. They could just rename method completely and change both arguments and result types completely: the effect would be same - not working.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25705596/1441122).

Comment: I have discovered that even if you write `Set<Chunk> chunks = wrap.chunksAddPlayer.keySet();` (note that the code is compatible with Java 7) and compile with Java 8, it will convert to the `KeySetView` during compilation, which means you won't be able to use it in Java 7.