# "The requested resource is not available" deploy spring-boot application in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I am getting the requested resource () is not available displayed in the browser and I can not understand what I am doing wrong.

I know, too many posts about this question but i still this error,
read the official documentation did not help me [spring boot maven plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging).

Is working properly on the IDE (embedded tomcat).

[image]

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>netgloo</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-mysql-hibernate</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-mysql-hibernate</name>
<description> Spring Boot web application with Hibernate Spatial</description>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1200-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20160212</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <start-class>netgloo.Application</start-class>
  <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
  <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
  <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
  <id>JBOSS</id>
  <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
 </repository>
 </repositories>

 <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <finalName>kgeo</finalName>
</build>

</project>
```

main Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  return application.sources(Application.class);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

main Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("name", name);
  return "index";
  }

}
```

This sample work without problems [java sample war](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/)

in Catalina log i can see an error

> " Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;"

reading around this can be generated by a mismatch of java versions,  in my editor i started with java8 and then i went down to 7, currently i'm building with maven3 that uses open-jdk 7 and Tomcat7 the same

Comment: Can you show the url you are trying to connect to. And also, what context has it deployed under. This should be displayed on the tomCat Manager page.

Comment: Hello the URL is "http://localhost:8080/kgeo/" , do you mean the tomcat7-admin package?

Comment: Yes, I mean the url localhost:8080/manager.. It should show you the application that you have deployed.

Comment: The context path is "/kgeo",  in the catalina log i show errors " Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;"

Comment: set both the source and target java levels in your pom.xml file to be 1.7

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24448723/3080094) appears to confirm you have a Java 7 / Java 8 incompatibility.

Comment: I compiled with maven that used jdk7 but i started tomcat7 with jdk8, with this configuration i can start the app, currently i'm looking for a method to know which maven dependency in my pom uses the problematic class